# Select only a row of two with a same field

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to solve this sql problem.
For example i have this:

```
 A1              TIER        DATE
TRY10,49         Tier 7      01/01/2013 
TRY104,99        Tier 51     01/07/2015 
TRY104,99        Tier 54     01/01/2013 
TRY1049,99       Tier 84     01/01/2013 
TRY11,19         Tier 6      01/01/2013 
TRY111,99        Tier 55     01/01/2013 
TRY111,99        Tier 52     01/07/2015
```

I want to select only rows with smaller Tier when A1 of a row it's equal to A1 of another row.

For example A1 of the second row is equal to A1 of the third.
So I want only the second row because Tier 51 < Tier 54.

So the query should become:

```
 A1              TIER      DATE
TRY10,49         Tier 7    01/01/2013       
TRY104,99        Tier 51   01/07/2015    
TRY1049,99       Tier 84   01/01/2013   
TRY11,19         Tier 6    01/01/2013   
TRY111,99        Tier 52   01/07/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select A1, min(tier) from tablename group by A1; (provided the tier values are numeric)
```

Comment: if i have other different field, group by doesn't work.

Comment: A1                     TIER               DATE
TRY10,49          Tier 7         01/01/2013
TRY104,99        Tier 51       01/07/2015
TRY104,99        Tier 84       01/01/2013
TRY11,19          Tier 6         01/07/2015
TRY11,19          Tier 52       01/01/2013

Comment: In that case we can have that date column also in the group by. select date,A1,min(tier) from table group by A1,date;

Comment: @StefanoCarboni - You didn't mention that in your original requirement. The answer will work on the dataset you gave. So if that works for you, then accept it and if not then specify what is the problem in the query with reference to your input data in example.

Comment: if i put date in group by the query returns both the row with equal A1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
                 with t1 as(      
                 select A1, min(tier) as min_tier from tablename group by A1
                 )
                 select t2.* from tablename t2,t1 where t2.tier=t1.min_tier
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query. It will suffice your conditions.

```
SELECT b.nm,
  b.tr,
  b.dt
FROM
  (SELECT a.nm,
    a.tr,
    a.dt,
    row_number() over(partition BY a.nm order by to_number(trim(SUBSTR(a.tr,5,LENGTH(a.tr))))) rnk
  FROM
    (SELECT 'TRY10,49'      AS nm,
      'Tier 7'              AS tr,
      to_date('01/01/2013') AS dt
    FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'TRY104,99'      AS nm,
      'Tier 51'             AS tr,
      to_date('01/07/2015') AS dt
    FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'TRY104,99'      AS nm ,
      'Tier 54'             AS tr,
      to_date('01/01/2013') AS dt
    FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'TRY1049,99'     AS nm,
      'Tier 84'             AS tr,
      to_date('01/01/2013') AS dt
    FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'TRY11,19' AS nm, 'Tier 6' AS tr, to_date('01/01/2013') AS dt FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'TRY111,99'      AS nm,
      'Tier 55'             AS tr,
      to_date('01/01/2013') AS dt
    FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'TRY111,99'      AS nm,
      'Tier 52'             AS tr,
      to_date('01/07/2015') AS dt
    FROM dual
    )a
  )b
WHERE b.rnk = 1;
```

Comment: What if he added another row of data?It looks like this query is hard coded

Comment: Yes he can add another row. The only thing whichbi hard coded is the substring part as 'Tier' is constant as per the question raised

Comment: Union is used just to replicate the data scenarios in this case.

Comment: A small point; if you're making up data like this, use UNION ALL, rather than UNION. UNION will force a distinct, which could remove rows you want to be present. Cf: `select * from (select 1 id from dual union select 1 id from dual);` vs `select * from (select 1 id from dual union all select 1 id from dual);`

Comment: Yupps dats true. Almost forgot. Thanks :)